# What do you call this React Component pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am having a hard time finding some documentation on this pattern.
Does it have a name?

`TextBase` is a styled component. so I can extend it as following:
`Text.H1 = withComponent('h1')` however I want html attributes to be passed as well. Hence the function component. However when I extend my `Text` component the props are being overridden, resulting with all components being h1's.

```
const Text = (props) => {
   const { children, testid, ...rest } = props;
   return <TextBase data-testid={testid} {...rest}>{children}</TextBase>
}
Text.defaultProps = {color: 'red'}

Text.H1 = Text
Text.H1.defaultProps = { as: 'h1'}

Text.H2 = Text
Text.H2.defaultProps = { as: 'h2'}

Text.H3 = Text
Text.H3.defaultProps = { as: 'h3'}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question, are you referring to the static priorities like `Text.H1`, `Text.H2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding the function call using this or use arrow function or manually bind the function using bind. I am sure it will work. Reference fault is all this is

Comment: `Text.H1 = Text.bind(this)` worked. Do you mind explaining how?

Comment: Well right now, you did not created an instance of Text and it was not referring to your H1/H2/H3/h4 but rather it was referring to globally defined Text functional component. we needed to bind it in order to get the achieved result. Makes sense?

Comment: Yep thanks. Tho I didn't bind this but `Text.bind(Text)`. When building my modules `this` is undefined.